# LuaLaTeX does not work anymore since last MiKTeX 2.9 update ("fatal format file error")

Tags: miktex, luatex

I just recently updated Miktex via the update wizard, and after that LuaLaTeX fails to generate any output. At first I thought it would have to do something with SIunitx, because I received an error there and it was used in the file I tried to employ LuaTeX on (SIunitx, was located into another package I think), but that wasn't the case. (SIunitx still doesn't work, because MiKTeX reports

```
"Message: Unknown archive file size.
Data: expl3
Source: libraries\miktex\packagemanager\internal.h
[...]"
```

when I try to get expl3 via the package manager.

Anyway, I then tried to use as few packages as possible to rule out some incompatibilities introduced by the new update or something like that, and tried to use LuaLaTeX on the following file:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

And all I get is

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011052811 <rev 4277>

<Fatal format file error; I'm stymied>
```

No log-file, no output, nada, only this error message. pdfTeX and the latex-dvips-ps2pdf-way both work without any problems (at least on the above file).

I could really use some help, since everything worked just fine about two weeks ago until my last update.

Please let me know if you want to get further information or anything like that to help me with my problem.

Oh, I almost forgot (in case it's important):

OS: Windows Vista Home Premium (32bit),

MiKTeX 2.9 (just updated :/)

---

I don't know whether I should make another separate question out of this, but I've got another problem with `luatex`, but only indirectly. I think I already know the cause, so I, more or less, just want to verify whether this is an issue of my own local installation, or a "global" problem:

Not a long time ago, there was another MiKTeX-Update, so I updated. But then I tried to compile another document with `lualatex` that worked before, but `lualatex` didn't create a document at all, while not reporting any real problems (at least not via Texmaker). So I looked into the folder of the file, and voila, `lualatex`or `luatex`(:O) created a folder, named "luatex-cache" and a log file, but nothing more. I then tried to isolate the problem by making a minimal example and first found out, that it probably isn't a `luatex`-problem itself, since sth. like:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

was compiled without any problems. I then continuously added more packages and I think the troublemaker could be `luatextra`. Again, the only output of

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

was: a folder named "luatex-cache" with an empty subfolder named "generic" and a log-file. The last 4 lines of the log-file can be seen below (I hope these are sufficient):

```
.
.
.
Lua module: luaotfload 2011/04/21 1.25 OpenType layout system.
luaotfload: loading file C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/otfl
-luat-dum.lua.
quiting: fix your readable cache path
```

If the moderators think this is important enough to post it as a separate question, I'm happy to do that. :D

Comment: Have you tried the miktex mailing list ?

Comment: Try to build the lualatex format manually: miktex settings, tab format, select lualatex and click on "build".

Comment: @Taco: No, actually I didn't, because I thought that this is a problem only I'm having, but I just looked at the list and thus solved my xfrac-problem (l3kernel was missing I think), so thank you for your hint.

Comment: @Ulrike: I already tried that (looked at the MiKTeX mailing list again and found someone who seemingly got a solution for my problem (I think it was exactly what you wrote)), but unfortunately it didn't work for me. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @Lustique. What does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get an error during the format generation? Do you have a multiuser installation? If yes: did you create the formats in user or admin mode? Btw: lualatex works fine for me. Regarding expl3: The latex3-files has been rearranged. expl3 and xpackages will be removed from miktex, the files are now in l3kernel and l3packages. Sync in the package manager (user + admin mode) the repositories to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Ulrike: Oh, sorry. I meant that it didn't change anything. I still got the same error message. The format generation worked without any error messages, but format generation for LuaTeX itself didn't really work, because MiKTeX didn't download luatexiniconfig.tex. Although there was no error message, every time I tried to build LuaTeX, it still told me it had to download luatexiniconfig.tex. Well, although I actually don't really know what a multiuser installation is in this context (:o), I do everything concerning MiKTex in admin mode.

Comment: lualatexiniconfig should be in miktex-luatex-base. But it is rather new and I think there was a packaging confusion. Go to the package manager and resync the repository. Do it in admin and user mode. Then run an update. At best as admin and user too. (It is quite difficult to do "everything" in admin mode in miktex. If you are compiling in a user account with on-the-fly enabled you will do quite a lot things in user mode.) Run on the command line `kpsewhich --engine=luatex lualatex.fmt` to find out if you are using a global or a local fmt.

Comment: @Ulrike: I did what you wrote, but both in user and in admin mode there was no update available. The "kpsewhich --engine=luatex lualatex.fmt"-thing said: ".../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/...".

Comment: @Lustique you should not update but synchronize the repository (package manager -> menu repositories). Regarding the path of lualatex.fmt: You deleted the important part: the account. It is "all users" or your personal account?

Comment: I did synchronize the repositories and then tried to update, but there were no updates available. Sorry, I thought the `/Local/`-part would be sufficient. It was my personal account, i.e. my name, so I wanted to exclude it (I could have just written `username` but obviously that would have been to easy :D), not "all users". Oh, and it still doesn't work, although _currently_ it's not _that important_ anymore, because I used PDFTex for my last document.

Comment: @Ulrike: Yesterday I tried to run `lualatex`again, having no success doing so (I felt like I should try again). Then I reinstalled my whole `MiKTeX`-distribution ("Basic MiKTeX 2.9") and `lualatex`worked fine until I updated `MiKTeX`: `lualatex` 0.6... worked, 0.7... doesn't work at all. The same error message. I then downloaded "MiKTeX Portable", which worked well, but again only until I updated it (`lualatex`from 0.6 to 0.7). Is there any possibility to downgrade to 0.6 or anything like that?

Comment: Check again the path of the fmt wich `kpsewhich`. Find the fmt and check its date. Then go to miktex settings (user mode if the `fmt` is in your user profile) and rebuild the lualatex format. Check if the date has changed.

Comment: @Ulrike: It did what you wrote, but the date didn't change (still was 06.08.2011). Then I changed that "format-attribute-thingy" (sorry, don't know what to call it :O, the thing in the "Formats"-tab in the MiKTeX-settings program) in user-mode to nothing (was on "exclude"), refreshed again, and `lualatex` successfully compiled (?) my minimal example. Thank you so much! I only did what I mentioned above in admin-mode before and it never changed anything. I sincerely hope it keeps on working now...

Comment: I have the same problem, and it's nothing to do with LuaTeX. It arose for me from following the instructions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67768/times-new-roman-font, but it also arises by going to MikTeX package manager and installing expl3 (although why it's required I can't imagine). MikTeX give the following information ``starting package maintenance... installation directory: C:\Users\jf3243\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 package repository: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ lightweight database digest: b5c327843d7508f1caa13b621ac8f5cb``

Answer (score 4):

I wrote about this bug to the maintainer of MiKTeX about two weeks ago, but got no answer.

Thus I installed TeX Live 2010. If you know what you are doing, you can do this:

1. Start the installation process of TeX Live 2010. Wait until it created all the folders. Abort the installation.
2. Copy all the LaTeX packages and the respective documentation from MiKTeX to the corresponding folders of TeX Live.
3. Start installation process again.
4. Afterwards get the update of luatex from tlcontrib.

Comment: Is there no other way? I really like this "I'll do almost everything for you automatically"-approach of MiKTeX. Or is this also possible when using TeXLive (without too much of an effort, since I'm already rather challenged by using LaTeX/LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX so I don't want a distribution that is also as complicated to maintain :o)?

Comment: Because I, more or less, only once tried to change something by myself (add the ccicons package to my MiKTeX, because the provided version didn't work at all) and somehow wrecked the whole distribution this way; I'm actually rather averse to the idea of having to do more things myself.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem before. When I downloaded the latest unicode-math packages from GitHub, it worked fine. I don't understand the connection, and it may be specific to my computer, but you can give it a try.

Comment: It didn't work for me. :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Miktex 2.9.

I use Windows 7.

I fixed it by setting an Environment variable named TEXMFCACHE which in my case to

`c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Miktex\2.9.`

It worked.

Comment: I am using WnEdt 8.0 in Wndows XP and I receive the same error. How can I modify my program to make it work?

Comment: I have installed TeX Live 2010 and set in my compiler (WnEdt 8) the new path for the executable file (C:\Program Files\texlive\2013\bin\win32\lualatex.exe). Now it works.