# Times new roman font?

Tags: fonts, times

I want this font:

[image: ttp://i45.tinypic.com/igdcac.png]

But everything I've tried makes ugly pseudo-times new roman font in comparison. What I've tried based on the research I've done so far;

1. `\usepackage{mathptmx}`
2. `\usepackage{times}`

I use Windows 7.

Comment: This font is not Times New Roman, but New Century Schoolbook. See the properties of the [PDF of the article](http://finance.wharton.upenn.edu/~aedmans/Blockholders.pdf).

Comment: Woah my bad. Journal of Finance in instructions says we need to submit Times New Roman for final edition so I just assumed ... It's "\usepackage{fouriernc}" for new century schoolbook if anyone is interested after reading Philippe's comment!

Comment: Note that the journal may well want you to submit in TNR. They will replace the fonts with their choice in preparing the article for publication. One reason they may do this is that they may be using commercial fonts but they can more-or-less count on authors having access to TNR (or near enough).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, and use:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

This is true Times New Roman, via modern TeX engines.

---

**Note:**
`mathptmx` and `times` packages (and `txfonts`) both use URW NimbusRomNo9L font, a clone of Times. AFAIK, it is very similar to Times. You can also use TeX Gyre Termes (based on Nimbus Roman), and XITS (based on STIX project) available in TeX dist.

There is indeed a `timesnew` package (in `pclnfss` bundle, without actual fonts) available in CTAN. It needs more configuration to make it work, using pdfLaTeX/Dvips.

And it is also possilbe to install Windows TTF fonts e.g. Times New Roman for pdfTeX, it is more tricky for normal users and the technique becomes outdated since XeTeX and LuaTeX are better choices.

Comment: LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX both just end in "Transcript written on filename.log", but won't actually make the PDF? (and I can't click "dvi pdf" to make the pdf like I would using LaTeX).

Comment: @IssacM: I've no idea what you meet. Maybe you could provide more information (by editing your question). Note: Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX produce PDF files directly.

Comment: Problem solved. I was just used to it popping up after creation instead of stealthily being created in the folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, really I solved this problem by writing my thesis using any font under the software TexMaker 3.5, then when I finished writing, I recompiled it with another software called MiKTeX 2.9. Now, under MiKTeX 2.9, change the typesetter to XeLaTeX, at this point you can apply the answer of @Leo Liu. In other words, you can add the following to your code and compile it without any problem. \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Times New Roman} Good luck

Comment: @Montadar MiKTeX is a distribution. TeXMaker is a front end. Which font you use depends on what you have installed. Since you are using XeLaTeX and using system fonts, it makes no difference whether you use MiKTeX or another TeX distribution. And either is completely compatible with TeXMaker. Note that this will only work if you do actually have TNR installed as a system font. Almost certain to be true on Windows. Less likely on Mac OS X. Unlikely on GNU/Linux. If you don't have it, you will get a substitution, of course.

Comment: Trying this gives me: fontspec error: "font-not-found".

Comment: I also get the error  `fontspec error: "font-not-found"`. I launched a separate question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460458/fontspec-error-font-not-found

Comment: @LeoLiu The problem of your fantastic answer is that `ligatures` don't work if you are working with Windows (I think MaC includes the ligatures). Regarding your comment about `mathptx`and `times`package, I don't know if they use the font you say. But, anyway, Numbus Roman No9 L is a free font practically identical to Times New Roman and it includes the ligatures. It is avaible [here (FREE)](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/nimbus-roman-no9-l). Finally, I'd like you to develop your note about `pclnfss` package. It is avaible in the MiKTeX's repository but I haven't managed to make it work.

Comment: Good catch @Dog_69, I'm also missing ligatures on (debian) linux, texlive, mscorefonts installed via apt. Going to go with Nimbus for now.