# Change font to "Times New Roman" in PDFLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Can anyone help me to change the font to "Times New Roman" in PDFLaTeX?

I already tried using the commands below without results:

```
% Font selection
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want specifically Times New Roman, or a font  of the family?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)! see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153558/92620

Comment: I said Times New Roman because I'm used to Word, but I can also use another equivalent font

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make my document use the Times font, both for the text and the math?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and-the-math)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Times new roman font?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67768/times-new-roman-font)

Comment: Andrew thank you but it replied this:
 ! LaTeX Error: File `fontaxes.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read >

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are compiling with `pdflatex`, this is one of several ways to get Times New Roman font for both math and text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

`\setmainfont` is a command of the `fontspec` package, which you can't use with the `pdflatex` engine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Andrew.
It works but equations in math mode ($ equation $) still don't have the font Times New Roman. Can you solve this problem as well?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Technically yes, nrwtxmath selects a font of math symbols that blend well with Times New Roman but are a separate font. This is what all math font packages in classic LaTeX do. You might look at `unicode-math` package for an alternative approach if you really need it to be a single font.

Comment: Thank you but it seems unicode-math package doesn't run with PDFLaTeX

Comment: Pdflatex only allows a certain number of slots for characters, enough for the basic English alphabet and most common symbols. If you want more symbols than that, you have to change to a different set of characters. This is done by having different font files for these different sets of characters. This limitation is built into the pdflatex program (oversimplifying a bit) and is a relic of an earlier era when computer memory was much more limited. If you want to use the full Unicode range of a single font, you have to use a different engine, xelatex or lualatex with fontspec package.