# changing font size in textmaker editor doesn't change font in the pdf

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, texmaker

[image: this is my latex file]

I've changed the font size to 14 in Times New Roman.It only changes font on the file on the left,but pdflatex file on the right remains same whatever the fontsize is.How do i fix this?

Comment: Note: The *editor* font is not the same as the *document* font. The document font has to be selected using LaTeX commands and options. The *Editor* settings of TeXmaker do not change anything at the LaTeX document or the resulting PDF.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317554/change-font-to-times-new-roman-in-pdflatex

Answer (score 2):

As you said you changed the font size in the Latex *editor*. This is just a convenience for you to make your code more readable for yourself. To change the font size for your PDF document you have to tell Latex to scale the font as you like. It looks like you are using the simple classes. 
"The standard classes, article, report and book support 3 different font sizes, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt (by default 10pt). The font size is set through the optional argument at the beginning of your code, e.g.:"

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
```

If you want to scale your font size to 14pt you can use for example the following command

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
```

Also note the source for my examples: https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/

Comment: I even tried \documentclass[14pt]{article}, but it doesn't change the font size of pdf

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of your code?