# How to set a Times New Roman in Latex?

Tags: fonts

I am writing an article using LaTeX, and I want to set a Times New Roman font. Does anyone know how I can do it?
When I don't use the package, the text renders as below:
[image]

When I set `\usepackage{newtxtext}` in the header of my document, the  text gets shrunk.
[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{newtxtext}` for text and `\usepackage{newtxmath}` if you also want the math font to be times roman.  There are also several older implementations available, such as `\usepackage{times}` for text and `\usepackage{mathptmx}` for math

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317554/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153168/82917

Comment: I use `\usepackage{newtxtext}` and my text was shortened by 75 pages, it was skinned by 5 pages. When I use `\usepackage{times}` and `\usepackage{mathptmx}` text is no change. So why my text was skinned ?

Comment: It's a different font, so it's quite normal that the sizes change. In particular, `newtx` is slightly narrower than Computer Modern, and the default space is also somewhat narrower

Comment: The newtx packages have a scale option you can use if you'd like it to be slightly bigger: `\usepackage[scale=1.1]{newtxtext,newtxmath}` or whatever you find suitable; you may also need the setspace package to adjust the line spacing slightly as well. There are other Times like packages available as well like stix and TeX Gyre Termes. See the [catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html).

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
Times New Roman
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use that, but my text no change

Comment: this is the most direct answer to the question but times is a very old package, almost always better to use newtxtext.  @user245467 if your text does not change then you are already using times, please fix your question to have a small complete example like this that shows your problem.

Comment: I explain my problem in main post, Can you say why  the text shrinked when I use `\usepackage{newtxtext}` ?

Comment: @user245467, perhaps it's something in your text? How about providing an MWE for your situation?

Comment: I dont; know what is MWE ? But in your opinion the text which I show in my post use Times New Roman or not ?

Comment: @user245467, A minimal working example (in latex code) for your question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Actually, it is _always_ better to use `newtxtext`, as `times` package is said obsolete at [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/times).

Comment: @Olivier not necessarily

Comment: Times New Roman is a font licensed by Microsoft (non free). Times Roman is slightly different font licensed by Adobe (non free) and it is better. There are free alternatives to Times Roman (not to Times New Roman). For example Nimbus Roman No9 L (from URW), it is used as free alternative to Times Roman in GhostScript. Or Termes (from TeX Gyre) is very good equivalent to Times Roman. When one uses `times` package, then `ptmr` metric files are used and they are mapped to Nimbus Roman No9 L in `pdftex.map`. Result: you have not Times *New* Roman but a free alternative to Times Roman.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://www.sascha-frank.com/Fonts/Times_New_Roman.html), this should do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

With XeLaTeX, you can use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a MWE it's hard to know what your needs are, but a very simple solution could be this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
This is a text.
\end{document}
```

This will work if:

- You compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.
- The Times New Roman font is installed in your operating system (so usable by other software, like a web browser, a word processor, and so on).

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: @Jon It does work here, so you'll have to be a little more specific than that. Is the font installed in your operating system and what error message do you get?

Comment: I do apologize. Yes, it does work very well, but I got confused between Time New Roman, and Ariel, all our exams and tests have to be written in Arial point 11, for the main body, then bold at a certain point, of course, all of this is for "Word"