# How to get a "Times New Roman" font in a LaTeX pdf document?

Tags: fonts

The package `mathptmx` is giving "Times Roman" font. Instead, I need "Times New Roman" font in my LaTeX pdf document.

Comment: You can see at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67768/times-new-roman-font or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153168/how-to-set-document-font-to-times-new-roman-by-command. Your question is similar.

Comment: Nobody is going to notice the difference.

Comment: Times New Roman? Really????? Why not Comic Sans...

Comment: If you really need Times **New** Roman, and if you have a system that runs either MacOSX or Windows, just switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, load the `fontspec` package, and issue the instruction `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` in the preamble. If you want to beef up on some of the (rather minor!) differences between the two typefaces, do read Ilene Strizver's nice post [TypeTalk: Times Roman vs Times New Roman](http://creativepro.com/typetalk-times-roman-vs-times-new-roman/) from 2009. If, after reading the essay, you can readily recognize any salient differences, more power to you!

Comment: This query reminds me of "some package gives me Helvetica but I am supposed to use Arial" rants. Even though the differences between Helvetica and Arial are far more pronounced than those between Times Roman and Times New Roman, I've never encountered anyone in charge of enforcing such font rules who noticed that their rules were being violated. I used to work at a place that required Times New Roman *and* Arial for working papers. Tellingly, nobody in the publication office ever took notice that *my* papers employed Times Roman and Helvetica. To sum up: Relax -- and just write good papers.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer (and others): Here in the USA, it's fairly common for high school teachers to *require* Times New Roman.  I guess that they assume it's available on all computers and can be required as a form of standardization. (How teachers ever managed back in the day when everyone had a typewriter of a different make I don't know.)  These teachers also typically require 1-inch side margins (on 8.5-inch-wide letter paper), which yields 90-95 characters per line with 12pt Times New Roman; no doubt left over from the days when 1-inch margins allowed for 65-75 char per line on a typewriter).

Comment: @Mico: My child's teacher noticed and required re-submission of a paper that had been written in Hoefler Text (in Pages).  More different from Times New Roman than Times, of course, but I would have thought it a perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @dedded - I think most of us are aware of the fact that lots and lots of places require the use of Times New Roman, not just in the U.S. but pretty much everywhere where the Latin alphabet forms the main writing system. However, will the people supposedly in charge of enforcing their (by and large silly) typographic rules ever notice when somebody submits a document that uses Times Roman instead of Times New Roman (or, for that matter, Helvetica instead of Arial)? Casual empiricism tells me, "not exactly likely..."

Comment: @dedded - *Even I* :-) can tell at a glance if a document is typeset in Hoefler Text or Times (New or not) Roman. Kudos to your child for daring to use a less tired typeface. Somewhat sad, really, that the teacher didn't reward the kid's willingness to stand out from the crowd.

Comment: In days of yore, when Windows 95 was rampant, I required college papers to be submitted with precise requirements, including font and margins, using a particular program that was in the tech center. No printouts. The digital files came to me, and I substituted a code for the student name. Then the anonymous files were available to other students, who would anonymously evaluate them (not for grade). The purpose of uniformity was to have the digital papers evaluated on content, rather than on layout. I assume this is the norm, possibly excepting creative writing.