# Lucida br, ! LaTeX Error: Command `\hbar' already defined

Tags: fonts, pdftex, captions, lucida

I have a school assigment which demands to use Times New Roman for general content and Lucida Caligraphy for image captions.

But I don't know how to do that, when I try to add [`lucidabr`](https://tug.org/store/lucida/lucida-sample.pdf) the compiler launches the next error (I think it crashes with tikz library `arrows.meta` but I'm not sure)

> ! LaTeX Error: Command `\hbar' already defined.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>
> l.673 ...reMathSymbol{\hbar}{\mathord}{arrows}{27}

```
\documentclass[UTF8,12pt]{article}

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\decimalpoint
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Fonts  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{16}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
% The line below produces the error mentioned in 1.%
\usepackage[altbullet]{lucidabr}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%  Other  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Math   %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction, group-separator={,}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%     Figures     %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usepackage[font=small, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%      Draws      %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%   Glossaries   %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{Glossary.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa,hyperref=true,url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setquotestyle[mexican]{spanish}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \nocite{*}
    \frenchspacing
    
    All the document is in Times New Roman but figure captions and math
    
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I use another packager for lucida and which? or How do I solve this error?

I appreciate your time and any help

I use PDFLatex.

Comment: Why are you loading `mathptmx` **and** `lucidabr`? Given its poorish math support I would never use `mathptmx`

Comment: I see no code that would use any kind of Lucida in captions. Besides, you're not using Times as a text font. Are you ***really*** sure you want captions like in [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2fKO.png)?

Comment: @egreg yes, that's what my teacher is asking

Comment: @daleif `mathptmx` provides support for Times font, `lucidabr` for lucida. as I'm using PDFLatex I didn't want to try with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67768/times-new-roman-font), because it says to be for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

Comment: Only for text, the math setup for times does not match times very well. In general there are nowadays much better setups. If course the best is never to use times in the first place

Comment: So how can I setup this? It's really confusing for me. Times new Roman for text, Lucida for captions and you also mention that I should avoid changing the math font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `\usepackage{lucidabr}` you will get Lucida for all the document.

The font family name for Lucida Calligraphy is `hlce`, so you can define a caption format that sets it as the font to use.

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{lucidacalligraphic}{\fontfamily{hlce}\selectfont#1#2#3\par}
\captionsetup{format=lucidacalligraphic}
```

Here's an edited version of your preamble, with some changes:

1. it's better to use `newtx` for Times, rather than the 25-year-old hack that's `mathptmx`;
2. package loading should be separated from settings; having the settings scattered between packages makes the preamble more difficult to maintain;
3. `hyperref` and `cleveref` should be loaded last;
4. there is no `UTF8` option.

Look also for `<---` notes and decide yourself what to keep.

I commented out `\input{Glossaries.tex}` because I don't have the file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%%% Packages

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%%%%%%%%%%%   Fonts  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % <--- obsolete
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{textcomp} % <--- no longer needed
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%  Other  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Math   %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%     Figures     %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%      Draws      %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%   Glossaries   %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa,hyperref=true,url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%% These should be last! %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

%%% settings

% biblatex
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\setquotestyle[mexican]{spanish}

% glossaries
\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries{Glossary.tex}

% graphicx
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

% sectional titles
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{16}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

% siunitx
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction, group-separator={,}}

% captions
\DeclareCaptionFormat{lucidacalligraphic}{\fontfamily{hlce}\selectfont#1#2#3\par}
\captionsetup{format=lucidacalligraphic}

% miscellaneous
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} % <--- Are you really sure?
\decimalpoint


\begin{document}

All the document is in Times New Roman but figure captions should
be in Lucida Calligraphy. Yes, that's right! Oh, no!

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{This should not be in Times}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I sympathize with you (and not with your teacher).