# Which font might produce the following output?

Tags: fonts

The following image is a scanned page from a book,
whose fonts I like to use.
Which fonts do youthink can produce the following math-output?
[image: CauchyInequality]

Comment: You can take a look at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html to see if there are any similar fonts there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may go with Tobjørns hint and search [the LaTeX font catalouge](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html) for some math fonts.

You can then take [Micos great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30066) to quickly render your formula with different fonts. This could look like this:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}

\setmathfont[version=lm]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version=xits]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=termes]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[version=pagella]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\newcommand{\formulas}{%
    \ensuremath{\displaystyle
    \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left|x_r\right|\left|y_r\right|\leqslant\sqrt{\left (\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left|x_r\right|^2\right)\left (\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left|y_r\right|^2\right)}}}

\begin{document}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\mathversion{lm}
\section*{Latin Modern}
\formulas

\setmainfont{XITS}
\mathversion{xits}
\section*{XITS, XITS Math}
\formulas

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\mathversion{termes}
\section*{Termes, Termes Math}
\formulas

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\mathversion{pagella}
\section*{Pagella, Pagella Math}
\formulas

\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image]

I hope you will find your font like this or another, which pleases you.

Comment: I am using WinEdt to compile tex files. Is it possible to make them work in WinEdt? I received errors when I tried to compile this. Or how can I compile a tex file in luatex?

Comment: I have downloaded 'luatex' files into a folder and moved my tex file into the same folder 'temp.tex'. Now I opened Command Prompt, enter the same folder and type 'lualatex temp.tex' but it returnes me the error 'quiting: fix your readble cache path'. I am sorry but it is the first time I hear about LuaTeX.

Comment: When I type `luatex` in my Command Prompt, I get the following `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011090216 (rev 4277)`. However, when I try to compile your file in WnEdt 8.0 (in Wndows XP) by setting the method to LuaLaTeX (as in the link you have provided) I get the error `quiting: fix your readble cache path`. No idea how can I fix it.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It seems to be an error with `MikTex 2.9` as I have searched through forums http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21735/lualatex-does-not-work-anymore-since-last-miktex-2-9-update-fatal-format-file. I installed `Tex Live 2010`. Then, set in my compiler `WnEdt 8` the new path for the executable file to be `C:\Program Files\texlive\2013\bin\win32\lualatex.exe`. It works now.